# 2dim Array with different sized second dimensions

Tags: c++, arrays

In the array

```
int a[][5] = {{1},{1,2}};
```

what is "the" size of its second dimension and what value  will

```
a[0][1]
```

have?

Does it even make sense to speak about the size or does it differ from "row" to "row"?

Is this considered bad practice?

Comment: That's not valid C++. All but the slowest dimension must be specified explicitly.

Comment: @ Kerrek SB Thanks for the pointer

Comment: If you fix *all* extents, then you're allowed to write the initializer as a flat list. But I don't think you can do that if you leave the inner dimension blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
int a[][5] = {{1},{1,2}};
```

the size of the first dimension is 2 (because there are two elements inside the outer `{}`), and the size of the second dimension is 5. Unmentioned elements in the initialiser are initialised to zero. So, your code is equivalent to:

```
int a[][5] = {{1,0,0,0,0},{1,2,0,0,0}};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid. It won't even compile:

```
test.cc:1:9: error: declaration of ‘a’ as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the curly bracket initialization notation with arrays, you must specify all the elements for all the dimensions your array is gonna have, so that piece of code would just give you a compile-time error.

If you want to have an array of containers of different size, consider using an array of vectors, or even a vector of vectors. To use them, just do an `#include <vector>` and you're done.